# Why am I getting error when I publish to config topic in Spring MQTT?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mqtt, spring-cloud, publish-subscribe

I'm sending a message to "config" topic from my Spring boot backend application

Here's my mqtt setup

```
final String mqttServerAddress =
            String.format("ssl://%s:%s", options.mqttBridgeHostname, options.mqttBridgePort);

    // Create our MQTT client. The mqttClientId is a unique string that identifies this device. For
    // Google Cloud IoT Core, it must be in the format below.
    final String mqttClientId =
            String.format(
                    "projects/%s/locations/%s/registries/%s/devices/%s",
                    options.projectId, options.cloudRegion, options.registryId, options.deviceId);

    MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    // Note that the Google Cloud IoT Core only supports MQTT 3.1.1, and Paho requires that we
    // explictly set this. If you don't set MQTT version, the server will immediately close its
    // connection to your device.
    connectOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);

    Properties sslProps = new Properties();
    sslProps.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2");
    connectOptions.setSSLProperties(sslProps);

    // With Google Cloud IoT Core, the username field is ignored, however it must be set for the
    // Paho client library to send the password field. The password field is used to transmit a JWT
    // to authorize the device.
    connectOptions.setUserName(options.userName);

    DateTime iat = new DateTime();
    if ("RS256".equals(options.algorithm)) {
        connectOptions.setPassword(
                createJwtRsa(options.projectId, options.privateKeyFile).toCharArray());
    } else if ("ES256".equals(options.algorithm)) {
        connectOptions.setPassword(
                createJwtEs(options.projectId, options.privateKeyFileEC).toCharArray());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid algorithm " + options.algorithm + ". Should be one of 'RS256' or 'ES256'.");
    }
    // [START iot_mqtt_publish]
    // Create a client, and connect to the Google MQTT bridge.
    MqttClient client = new MqttClient(mqttServerAddress, mqttClientId, new MemoryPersistence());

    // Both connect and publish operations may fail. If they do, allow retries but with an
    // exponential backoff time period.
    long initialConnectIntervalMillis = 500L;
    long maxConnectIntervalMillis = 6000L;
    long maxConnectRetryTimeElapsedMillis = 900000L;
    float intervalMultiplier = 1.5f;

    long retryIntervalMs = initialConnectIntervalMillis;
    long totalRetryTimeMs = 0;

    while ((totalRetryTimeMs < maxConnectRetryTimeElapsedMillis) && !client.isConnected()) {
        try {
            client.connect(connectOptions);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            int reason = e.getReasonCode();

            // If the connection is lost or if the server cannot be connected, allow retries, but with
            // exponential backoff.
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            if (reason == MqttException.REASON_CODE_CONNECTION_LOST
                    || reason == MqttException.REASON_CODE_SERVER_CONNECT_ERROR) {
                System.out.println("Retrying in " + retryIntervalMs / 1000.0 + " seconds.");
                Thread.sleep(retryIntervalMs);
                totalRetryTimeMs += retryIntervalMs;
                retryIntervalMs *= intervalMultiplier;
                if (retryIntervalMs > maxConnectIntervalMillis) {
                    retryIntervalMs = maxConnectIntervalMillis;
                }
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    attachCallback(client, options.deviceId);



    // The MQTT topic that this device will publish telemetry data to. The MQTT topic name is
    // required to be in the format below. Note that this is not the same as the device registry's
    // Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    String mqttTopic = String.format("/devices/%s/%s", options.deviceId, options.messageType);
    long secsSinceRefresh = ((new DateTime()).getMillis() - iat.getMillis()) / 1000;
    if (secsSinceRefresh > (options.tokenExpMins * MINUTES_PER_HOUR)) {
        System.out.format("\tRefreshing token after: %d seconds%n", secsSinceRefresh);
        iat = new DateTime();
        if ("RS256".equals(options.algorithm)) {
            connectOptions.setPassword(
                    createJwtRsa(options.projectId, options.privateKeyFile).toCharArray());
        } else if ("ES256".equals(options.algorithm)) {
            connectOptions.setPassword(
                    createJwtEs(options.projectId, options.privateKeyFileEC).toCharArray());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid algorithm " + options.algorithm + ". Should be one of 'RS256' or 'ES256'.");
        }
        client.disconnect();
        client.connect(connectOptions);
        attachCallback(client, options.deviceId);
    }

        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
        message.setQos(1);
        client.publish(mqttTopic, message);
```

here's the options class

```
public class MqttExampleOptions {
String mqttBridgeHostname = "mqtt.googleapis.com";
short mqttBridgePort = 8883;
String projectId = 
String cloudRegion = "europe-west1";
String userName = "unused";
String registryId = <I don't want to show>
String gatewayId = <I don't want to show>
String algorithm = "RS256";
String command = "demo";
String deviceId = <I don't want to show>
String privateKeyFile = "rsa_private_pkcs8";
String privateKeyFileEC = "ec_private_pkcs8";
int numMessages = 100;
int tokenExpMins = 20;
String telemetryData = "Specify with -telemetry_data";
String messageType = "config";
int waitTime = 120
}
```

When I try to publish message to topic "config" I get this error

```
ERROR 12556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() 
for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/iot-admin] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is Connection Lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:273) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:92) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:137) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar:na]
```

this is the message I am sending

```
{
"Led": {
    "id": "e36b5877-2579-4db1-b595-0e06410bde11",
    "rgbColors": [{
        "id": "1488acfe-baa7-4de8-b4a2-4e01b9f89fc5",
        "configName": "Terminal",
        "rgbColor": [150, 150, 150]
    }, {
        "id": "b8ce6a35-4219-4dba-a8de-a9070f17f1d2",
        "configName": "PayZone",
        "rgbColor": [150, 150, 150]
    }, {
        "id": "bf62cef4-8e22-4804-a7d8-a0996bef392e",
        "configName": "PayfreeLogo",
        "rgbColor": [150, 150, 150]
    }, {
        "id": "c62d25a4-678b-4833-9123-fe3836863400",
        "configName": "BagDetection",
        "rgbColor": [200, 200, 200]
    }, {
        "id": "e19e1ff3-327e-4132-9661-073f853cf913",
        "configName": "PersonDetection",
        "rgbColor": [150, 150, 150]
    }]
}
}
```

How can I properly send a message to a config topic without getting this error? I am able to send message to "state" topic, but not to "config" topic.